# PyInstaller: StopIteration Error when I import geopandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, centos7, pyinstaller, geopandas

I am trying to execute `PyInstaller` on a my script. I installed all of the required packages and the `.exe` is succesfully created.

But when I execute it on another machine, I get he Following error:

```
[2837] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_glib.py
[2837] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_pkgres.py
[2837] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py
[2837] LOADER: Running physiocap_templatized.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "physiocap_templatized.py", line 53, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 395, in load_module
  File "geopandas/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 395, in load_module
  File "geopandas/datasets/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
StopIteration
[2837] Failed to execute script physiocap_templatized
[2837] LOADER: OK.
[2837] LOADER: Cleaning up Python interpreter.
[2836] LOADER: Restoring signal handlers
[2836] LOADER: freeing args
[2836] LOADER: returning child exit status 255
[2836] LOADER: Back to parent (RC: 255)
[2836] LOADER: Doing cleanup
[2836] LOADER: Freeing archive status for /root/MyExe/physiocap_AB_templatized
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51957870/11664906)  but it didn't help. This is the list of packages I installed on the machine that executes `PyInstaller`: `pip freeze`:

```
aenum==2.1.2
altgraph==0.16.1
asn1crypto==0.24.0
astroid==1.6.6
attrs==19.1.0
backports.functools-lru-cache==1.5
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.5.0.1
cffi==1.12.3
Click==7.0
click-plugins==1.1.1
cligj==0.5.0
configobj==4.7.2
configparser==3.7.4
configshell-fb==1.1.23
contextlib2==0.5.5
coverage==3.6b3
cryptography==2.7
cycler==0.10.0
Cython==0.29.10
decorator==3.4.0
descartes==1.1.0
di==0.0.1
dis3==0.1.2
dnspython==1.12.0
enum==0.4.7
enum34==1.1.6
ez-setup==0.9
Fiona==1.7.11.post1
future==0.17.1
futures==3.1.1
GDAL==1.11.4
geopandas==0.3.0
geopy==1.12.0
idna==2.8
iniparse==0.4
ipaddress==1.0.16
IPy==1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
jwcrypto==0.2.1
kitchen==1.1.1
kiwisolver==1.0.1
langtable==0.0.45
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.1
macholib==1.11
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==2.2.4
mplleaflet==0.0.5
munch==2.3.2
nose==1.3.7
numpy==1.12.0
pandas==0.22.0
pefile==2019.4.18
perf==0.1
pyasn1==0.4.5
pyasn1-modules==0.2.5
pycparser==2.19
pycurl==7.19.0
pygobject==3.22.0
pygpgme==0.3
PyInstaller==3.4
pyliblzma==0.5.3
pyparsing==2.4.0
pyproj==1.9.5.1
pyshp==2.1.0
python-augeas==0.5.0
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-linux-procfs==0.4.9
pytz==2019.1
pyudev==0.15
pyxattr==0.5.1
schedutils==0.4
schema==0.7.0
scikit-learn==0.19.1
scipy==0.16.0
Shapely==1.6.4.post2
simplekml==1.3.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.12.0
slip==0.4.0
slip.dbus==0.4.0
subprocess32==3.5.4
urlgrabber==3.10
wrapt==1.11.2
yum-metadata-parser==1.1.4
```

I am on `Centos7` machine with `Python2.7.5` and `PyInstaller3.4`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try [this answer's solution ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54208040/11724795) :

> I don't use the geopandas datasets in my project/s so instead of
>   manually including them in my .spec file I just commented out the
>   `import geopandas.datasets` statement from: `File
>   "site-packages\geopandas\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>`.

It kind of worked for me - I did stop having this Stop Iteration error. 
Instead I got *another* error (in my case it's a CRS Error) but this one seems to be more easily solvable.

Anyway, there are definitely compatibility issues between pyinstaller and geopandas linked to its **dependencies** (pyproj, fiona...) so I think if you get more errors, it's also worth checking the import of each of these modules separately.

Comment: It did work! I now have a different error (core dump) but at least I no longer have a StopIteration one. Thank you!

Comment: For me, I change the file __init__ like this:

Original Code:

__all__ = ["available", "get_path"]

_module_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
_available_dir = [p for p in next(os.walk(_module_path))[1] if not p.startswith("__")]
_available_zip = {"nybb": "nybb_16a.zip"}
available = _available_dir + list(_available_zip.keys())
__all__ = ["available", "get_path"]

Code after changes:
_module_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
_available_zip = {"nybb": "nybb_16a.zip"}
available = list(_available_zip.keys())

Answer (score 0):

For me worked to comment on this line on my virtual environment:

```
## geopandas\__ init__. Py line 17 code “import geopandas. Datasets # noqa”
```

Then I run again pyinstaller and the EXE worked fine.