# Can't use shapely when generating .exe from python file with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, shapely

I'm trying to create a .exe file from a python code; in a part of my code, I use shapely to create a polygon and check if points are in or out of this polygon.
When I create a .exe from my python code without this part of the code, everything works fine, but when I add

```
from shapely import geometry
```

and try to create a .exe file, I get this error,

```
Error: geos_c.dll not found, required by hook-shapely.py.
Please check your installation or provide a pull request  
to PyInstaller to update hook-shapely.py.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: pyinstaller (and other smilar programs) sometimes has problem to find all needed modules and C/C++ libraries which it has to add to .exe - but it create special config file in which you can maually add missing elements. Read documetation for `pyinstaller`. Especially `how to use file .spec` and `what to do when something goes wrong`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51957870/9978945